# Zend_Form::setAction() uses current controller in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I declare a `publisher` controller:

```
class PublisherController extends Zend_Controller_Action {

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->view->form = $this->_getForm();
        $this->render('form');
    }

    public function dataPostAction()
    {
        //@TODO
    }

    protected function _getForm()
    {
        $form = new Zend_Form();            
        $form->setAction('publisher/dataPost')//Here, I DO NOT want to do: setAction('*/dataPost') with `*` means current controller.
             ->setMethod('post')
             ->setAttrib('id','publisher-form');

        $form->addElement('text', 'name',
            array(
                'label'=>'First Name',
                'class'=>'required'
            )
        );        
        $form->addElement('submit', 'Save');        
        return $form;
    }
}
```

Look at the line: `$form->setAction('publisher/dataPost')`

This means that I want to set the action for the form after submitting is `dataPost` of `publisher` controller.

Now I want do do `$form->setAction('*/dataPost')` with the `*` means current controller. Because current controller is `publisher` too.

But it does not work, or am I missing something? Can you tell me what is correct?

Comment: The '*' doesn't mean anything to PHP, it's just a part of a string. So '*/dataPost' is meaningless. If 'publisher/dataPost' is working why not just use that?

Comment: @vascowhite: Yes, I know that, I just want to ask another solution. In my opinion, if I have to type the name of controller, I can make incorrect... Am I wrong?

Comment: Well, taking it to the extreme you could do `$form->setAction($this->getRequest()->getControllerName().'/dataPost')` but in all honesty, that's making things way too complex and unnecessary slow. Just write the name, that's better to read :)

Comment: @Sam:Thanks so much for your help. Now I got this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`publisher/dataPost` is much easier to type than `$form->setAction($this->getRequest()->getControllerName().'/dataPost')`, so I would recommend you stick with what you are already doing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't normally use it in the zend form its self, but preferably in the actions view when calling the form using this code.

`<?php echo $this->setAction(url(/.../.../) );?>`

This is to echo the form you using in your action and also to set its action. So in short just stick to what you have or use sam's method but I think its better if you have something ACCURATE and working.

Answer (score -1):

I decide the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7723125/zend-fomrsetaction-uses-current-controller-in-zend-framework#comment-9397002) of [@Sam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/958642/sam) is the best answer for me.

#### Using the statement:

`$form->setAction($this->getRequest()->getControllerName().'/dataPost')`

---

#### UPDATE

From this question, I know that: "DO NOT be complex", and some guys here is don't agree so much with the above solution. Now I got this too. But, for this answer, I believe that I SHOULD check and confirm what is correct.

Comment: You are joking? You're worried about making a mistake typing 'publisher', so you replace it it with `$form->setAction($this->getRequest()->getControllerName().'/dataPost')`?! -1

Comment: +1: for @vascowhite's comment: And Can I ask you one question? Why did you think am I joking? I'm serious.

Comment: And if you post your answer (cc: @vascowhite) I will choose yours.

Comment: answer posted in response to your comment:).